# Would the bond length of boron trifluoride remain the same after electron donation?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond

Would the bond length of boron trifluoride remain the same after electron donation?

My guess is it should be the same, because if $\ce{BF3}$ donates electrons from the low energy occupied orbitals, it would not affect the bond length much.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Chemistry.SE! I suggest taking the short [tour] to better familiarize yourself with how the site works. Also, as this seems like a homework-type of question, I would read through [this](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange/142#142) discussion on how to ask a homework question.  You can also visit the [help] if you have any other questions.

Comment: Boron trifluoride is a very strong Lewis acid. Why is it donating electrons?

Answer (score 1):

BF<sub>3</sub> is a lewis acid as its octet is not complete and hence it will always have a tendency of forming a coordinate bond with a lewis base.

And talking about the bond length. B in BF<sub>3</sub> is sp<sup>2</sup>
 hybridized & therefore the contains an unhybridized p orbital in B that works as a vacant orbital for backbonding with the pair of electrons from fluorines. This develops a partial pie bond character in case of BF<sub>3</sub>.

When BF<sub>3</sub> accepts the coordinate bond from anyother lewis base, then it becomes sp<sup>3</sup> hybridised and also no vacant orbitals in B, hence no backbonding possible and hence no partial pie bond character.

Conclusion:
In BF<sub>3</sub>; we observe sp<sup>2</sup> hybridisation and also pie bond character due to backbonding and in BF<sub>3</sub>(X)^-   ,where X is the lewis base, it is sp<sup>3</sup> hybridised and also no pie bond character.

Pie bond character decreases the bond length.
In sp<sup>2</sup> hybridisation,due to more s-character, bond length is also shorter than sp<sup>3</sup> hybridisation.

sp<sup>2</sup> hybridisation + pie bond character is the reason of smaller bond length in BF<sub>3</sub> as compared to BF<sub>3</sub>(X)^- . So the bondlength changes when BF<sub>3</sub> accepts electron pairs. The reason being change in its hybridisation (i.e. sp<sup>2</sup> to sp<sup>3</sup>) and no pie bond character after accepting a coordinate bond from a lewis base.